# My PHP does not loop, only stops after first result

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a beginner in PHP and I am using wordpress.

I am calling a post title inside a form(Gravity Forms) and use this line of code:

```
add_filter('gform_field_value_testtitle', create_function("", '$value = testing_title(); return $value;' ));
```

And what i need to make is a function that allows me to pre populate one of the gravity forms fields with the post title, and i do that like this:

```
function testing_title() {
    global $wp_query;
    while ($postid = $wp_query->post->ID) {
        return $postid;
    }
}
```

This returns the first post id and then it stops. So I have a list of posts but with this only the first post appears, and the id is inserted in the form.

How do I get the rest of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"return" leaves your function.

if you want to retrieve the rest of the data, you should store it in a variable (i.e. an array) and return that variable after the loop finished.

Answer (score 1):

return will end the function, store the results in and array and return that once its finished.

```
function testing_title() {
    global $wp_query;

    $results = array();

    while ($postid = $wp_query->post->ID) {
        $results[] =  $postid;
    }
    return $results;
}
```